# Use multiple TPUs in Keras with TF

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-cloud-platform

How do I setup Keras model to use multiple TPUs for training? All the examples use a single TPU address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently correct way to use multiple TPUs is to pass list of addresses into the resolver:

```
TPU_ADDRESS1 = 'grpc://10.240.1.2:8470'
TPU_ADDRESS2 = 'grpc://10.240.2.2:8470'

tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model, 
        strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
            tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu = [TPU_ADDRESS1,TPU_ADDRESS2])))
```

**However TF 1.13 does *not* support more than 1 TPU**

Answer (score 1):

In keras, this is not officially provided YET.

But I know people are working very hard to develop this function for Keras.

At bottom tensorflow layer, they do provide some experimental function. See

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distribute_strategy

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_tpu

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-tpus

> "Experimental support for Cloud TPUs is currently available for Keras
> and Colab."
>
> In your Tensorflow program, you should use TPUClusterResolver to
> connect with the TPU gRPC server running on the TPU VM. The
> TPUClusterResolver returns the IP address and port of the Cloud TPU.
>
> Assigning ops to TPUs To make use of the TPUs on a machine, you must
> use the TensorFlow TPUEstimator API, which inherits from the
> high-level TensorFlow Estimator API.

It may not be exactly what you wanted e.g a local TPU cluster. But you can follow their way to get started

Personally, I never try with complicated multi gpu/tpu solution before. We only do simple single GPU training in school research. Here is what I can find to help you

So go join their beta and good luck!